# How to add with phpMyAdmin a new user meta field if a specific meta field already exists?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

How to add with phpMyAdmin in Wordpress database `my_usermeta` table a new user meta field with a new value if a specific meta field and value already exists? For all existing users that have that specific field and value! For example, if users have a `meta_key` "*department*" with `meta_value` *psychology*, add a new `meta_key` "*statute*" with the `meta_value` "*teacher*".

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation about what you mean by "meta field"?

Comment: Maybe "custom field", "extra field"? Not exactly what you ask, but: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the wordpress table called `tkf_usermeta`. You can insert a new row in there to create a new attribute as you describe.

In phpMyAdmin run something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tkf_usermeta`(`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (<user_id>,<meta_key>, <meta_value>)
```

Just sub in your user_id, and your key & value. Should get you what you're after

Simple iterative php code to insert a single meta key/value for all users:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('<host>', '<user>', '<password>', '<database>') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

$users = $mysqli->query("select id from tkf_users") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

$insertString = "INSERT INTO `tkf_usermeta`(`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (?,?,?)";

$key = "statute";//set to whatevever the key is, ie statute
$value = "teacher";//set to whatever the value is, ie teacher
$metaStmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertString);
while($result = $users->fetch_array()) {
    $metaStmt->bind_param("iss",$result['user_id'], $key, $value);
    $metaStmt->execute();     
}

$userStmt->close();
$metaStmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: How about all users, not only one?

Comment: You could just repeat the insert for each user, just sub in each user_id and run the insert for each one. If you nee da lot of customization it's probably worth looking at this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/ It would allow for simpler customization

Comment: You could write some php code to iterate over your users and call that insert statement. I'll edit and add it

Comment: @Iurie added the example, all you have to do is change the `mysqli_connect` params for your setup and it will work.

Comment: Code not worked, not added anything. And I received an error: **Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /home ...**, I suppose, from the last 3 lines.

Comment: Sounds like it's never making the connection. I added a simple error reporting statement to the connection line. See if that prints a useful error